# Predict n steps for multivariate time series forecasting

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, regression, forecasting, arima

In a multivariate time series forecasting, Do we need to pass the input variable values for prediction?. How it works if we have to predict n steps?

Let's say we have variable like Date, Age, Gender, Country, Customers count. Is it possible to predict customers count for next n periods with the historical data?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Python programming